# Increase the value of a specific row depending on the input of another table using triggers SQlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, triggers

My problem is this :
Whenever I insert a word into a table named A, table B must update it's value by +1 in the row with ID same as the number of letters in the input word.
This must be done with triggers.
For example if I input the word ("macaroni") on table A, table's B column named value with ID (8) must increase by 1.

For example

ID-value

8 - 1

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_value
after insert on A
for each ROW
BEGIN
 SELECT id FROM B LIMIT CHAR_LENGTH(A),1; 
 update B set value = value + 1;
end
```

It, of course, does not work a I am pretty new to SQLite so I would much appreciate your help on how to solve this!

EDIT: Table A contains one column(words) while Table B contains the two columns, the id and value. So we probably have to enter the value of the id every time we have a word length that wasn't previously added.

Comment: Post the definitions of the tables. Does table B contain rows with all the possible lebgths?

Comment: @forpas just edited it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the column `ID` in the table `B` is the primary key. 
If the table B does not contain a row for each possible length, you can use [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) inside the trigger, so that if a word with a new length is inserted in A then a new row with `value = 1` will be inserted in B, else the existing row will be incremented:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_value AFTER INSERT ON A
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO B(id, value)
  SELECT LENGTH(NEW.word), 1
  ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE
  SET value = value + 1;
END
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2656385c74a8b6a05ef849d201b23dc0).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The demonstration is really helpful!
I was wondering in order add a trigger in the event of deletion, if i would use the same (almost) method as the one you described.

Comment: @ReactingInnocent check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a666192da4c9a4b0559ba3d5db37df33

Answer (score 1):

Assuming table definitions like

```sql
create table wordlens(id integer primary key, count integer);
create table words(id integer primary key, word text);
```

Something like this trigger:

```sql
create trigger update_value after insert on words
begin
  insert or ignore into wordlens values (length(new.word), 0);
  update wordlens set count = count + 1 where id = length(new.word);
end;
```

First it adds a new row for the given length if it doesn't already exist in the length table, and then it increases the appropriate row's count by 1.

Example usage:

```sql
sqlite> insert into words(word) values ('macaroni');
sqlite> select * from wordlens;
id  count
--  -----
8   1
sqlite> insert into words(word) values ('abcdefgh');
sqlite> select * from wordlens;
id  count
--  -----
8   2
```